# Conditional binding doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, javafx

Take a look at `Layout` -> `initPanelSizeBinding()`. The problem is `then()` is being executed even though `panelProperty.get()` is `null`. Am I doing something wrong?

You can try it out yourself, below is the full reproducible example. (Tested on OpenJFX 15)

Reproducible example - [click here (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/RTgndSUv)

or take a look below:

***Code:***

Main.java

```
public class Main {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Layout layout = new Layout();
        /*
        WARNING: Exception while evaluating binding
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Panel.getWidth()" because the return value of "javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty.get()" is null
            at Layout.lambda$initPanelSizeBinding$0(Layout.java:20)
            at javafx.beans.binding.Bindings$6.computeValue(Bindings.java:358)
            at javafx.beans.binding.ObjectBinding.get(ObjectBinding.java:157)
            at javafx.beans.binding.ObjectExpression.getValue(ObjectExpression.java:49)
            at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.addListener(ExpressionHelper.java:53)
            at javafx.beans.binding.ObjectBinding.addListener(ObjectBinding.java:77)
            at javafx.beans.binding.When$ObjectCondition.<init>(When.java:757)
            at javafx.beans.binding.When$ObjectConditionBuilder.otherwise(When.java:854)
            at Layout.initPanelSizeBinding(Layout.java:24)
            at Layout.<init>(Layout.java:12)
            at Main.main(Main.java:4)
         */
    }
 
}
```

Layout.java

```
public final class Layout {
 
    public Layout() {
        panelSize.bind(initPanelSizeBinding(panel));
        // there's no need to do anything with panel, because it's an example
    }
 
    private ObjectBinding<Dimension2D> initPanelSizeBinding(ObjectProperty<Panel> panelProperty) {
        return Bindings
                .when(panelProperty.isNotNull())
                .then(Bindings.createObjectBinding(
                        () -> new Dimension2D(panelProperty.get().getWidth(), panelProperty.get().getHeight()),
                        Bindings.selectDouble(panelProperty, "width"),
                        Bindings.selectDouble(panelProperty, "height"))
                )
                .otherwise(new Dimension2D(150.0, 150.0));
    }
 
    //------Properties
 
    //panel
 
    private final ObjectProperty<Panel> panel = new SimpleObjectProperty<>
            (Layout.this, "panel", null);
 
    public ObjectProperty<Panel> panelProperty() {
        return panel;
    }
 
    public void setPanel(Panel value) {
        panel.set(value);
    }
 
    public Panel getPanel() {
        return panel.get();
    }
 
    //panelSize
 
    private final ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Dimension2D> panelSize = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>
            (Layout.this, "panelSize");
 
    public ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Dimension2D> panelSizeProperty() {
        return panelSize.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }
 
    public Dimension2D getPanelSize() {
        return panelSize.get();
    }
 
}
```

Panel.java

```
public final class Panel {
 
    private final VBox rootNode;
 
    public Panel() {
        rootNode = new VBox();
        width.bind(rootNode.widthProperty());
        height.bind(rootNode.heightProperty());
    }
 
    public VBox getRootNode() {
        return rootNode;
    }
 
    //------Properties
 
    //width
 
    private final ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper width = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper
            (Panel.this, "width");
 
    public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty widthProperty() {
        return width.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }
 
    public double getWidth() {
        return width.get();
    }
 
    //height
 
    private final ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper height = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper
            (Panel.this, "height");
 
    public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty heightProperty() {
        return height.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }
 
    public double getHeight() {
        return height.get();
    }
 
}
```

Comment: @kleopatra just created minimal reproducible example (contains just three classes, you can just copy-paste them into an empty java project - tested on openjfx15) - included in my posted

Comment: hmm ... can reproduce it - no idea what's going wrong. _Looks_ okay - hopefully one of the binding experts might have an explanation :)

Comment: @kleopatra Looks like it's a consequence of how `ExpressionHelper` is implemented; it calls `observable.getValue()` when adding an `InvalidationListener` which causes the observable to compute its value. I don't understand why it does this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `then` and `otherwise` bindings are, at least as of JavaFX 15, evaluated *eagerly*<sup>1</sup>. I'm not sure if they're *supposed*<sup>1</sup> to be evaluated eagerly, but they are. So while you may be conditioning upon `panelProperty.isNotNull()` the binding you create with `createObjectBinding` still attempts to compute the value no matter what. In this case, it's probably better to forgo the use of `Bindings.when` and simply implement the logic yourself in a custom binding:

```java
private ObjectBinding<Dimension2D> initPanelSizeBinding(ObjectProperty<Panel> panelProperty) {
  DoubleBinding width = Bindings.selectDouble(panelProperty, "width");
  DoubleBinding height = Bindings.selectDouble(panelProperty, "height");
  return Bindings.createObjectBinding(
      () -> {
        Panel panel = panelProperty.get();
        if (panel == null) {
          return new Dimension2D(150.0, 150.0);
        }
        return new Dimension2D(width.get(), height.get());
      },
      panelProperty,
      width,
      height);
}
```

---

<sup>1. *Looking into it more, it appears the conditional binding does try to be lazy. Unfortunately, the act of the condition binding adding a listener to the `then` observable causes said observable to be validated (and thus eagerly evaluated). This is a consequence of how `ExpressionHelper` is implemented, which calls `observable.getValue()` to validate it. I don't understand why the code does this, especially considering it's an `InvalidationListener` being added which is supposed to be the lazy listener.*</sup>

Comment: hmm interesting .. didn't think the _why_ through just musing: without having an initial value, how to decide whether a setting will invalidate?

Comment: @kleopatra The observable starts off as "invalid". So if the initial value changes it's not like the observable can get "more invalidated". When the value is first needed is when it should be first calculated. At the very least it doesn't make sense that adding an `InvalidationListener` should force the observable to validate. Things may have to work differently if there's a `ChangeListener` involved, but `InvalidationListener` is supposed to be lazy (at least as I understand it).

Comment: good point - the mere act of adding a listener shouldn't change the state of the binding ..

Comment: did a quick test: removed the validation from ExpressionHelper .. and got failing tests in controls (TextInputControlTest.selectedTextChange) and graphics (around transforms). So looks like internal code relies on the (undocumented and not quite understandable, for me ;) implementation. Need to live with it, I guess.