# Bindings.select() dependencies are not updated

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using `Bindings.select()` in order to access properties that may be null (take a look at `ClassOne` -> `initClassTwoSizeBinding()`). Even though I put it as dependencies, it seems it doesn't work, it just doesn't care about property changes. I prepared working example, take a look below. Am I doing everything right?

***CODE:***

***Main.java***

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassOne classOne = new ClassOne();
        ClassTwo classTwo = new ClassTwo();

        classOne.setClassTwo(classTwo);

        classTwo.setWidth(100.0);
        classTwo.setHeight(100.0);
    }

}
```

***ClassOne.java***

```
public final class ClassOne {

    public ClassOne() {
        classTwoSize.bind(initClassTwoSizeBinding(classTwo));
    }

    private ObjectBinding<Dimension2D> initClassTwoSizeBinding(ObjectProperty<ClassTwo> classTwoProperty) {
        return Bindings.createObjectBinding(
                () -> {
                    System.out.println("THIS CODE IS EXECUTED");
                    ClassTwo classTwo = classTwoProperty.get();
                    return classTwo == null ? new Dimension2D(150, 150)
                            : new Dimension2D(classTwo.getWidth(), classTwo.getHeight());
                },
                classTwoProperty,
                Bindings.select(classTwoProperty, "width"),
                Bindings.select(classTwoProperty, "height")
        );
    }

    //classTwo

    private final ObjectProperty<ClassTwo> classTwo = new SimpleObjectProperty<>
            (ClassOne.this, "classTwo", null);

    public ObjectProperty<ClassTwo> classTwoProperty() {
        return classTwo;
    }

    public void setClassTwo(ClassTwo value) {
        classTwo.set(value);
    }

    public ClassTwo getClassTwo() {
        return classTwo.get();
    }

    //classTwoSize

    private final ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Dimension2D> classTwoSize = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>
            (ClassOne.this, "classTwoSize");

    public ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Dimension2D> classTwoSizeProperty() {
        return classTwoSize.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public Dimension2D getClassTwoSize() {
        return classTwoSize.get();
    }

}
```

***ClassTwo.java***

```
public final class ClassTwo {

    //width

    private final ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper width = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper
            (ClassTwo.this, "width");

    public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty widthProperty() {
        return width.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public double getWidth() {
        return width.get();
    }

    public void setWidth(double val) {
        //ONLY FOR TESTING PURPOSES!!!
        width.set(val);
    }

    //height

    private final ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper height = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper
            (ClassTwo.this, "height");

    public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty heightProperty() {
        return height.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height.get();
    }

    public void setHeight(double val) {
        //ONLY FOR TESTING PURPOSES!!!
        height.set(val);
    }

}
```

Comment: Tested on OpenJFX 15

Comment: I don't see anything querying the `classTwoSize` property. Try adding a `ChangeListener` to the property (that e.g. prints out the old and new values) before changing the width/height and see if there's any output.

Comment: @Slaw I added a `ChangeListener` and the code execute two times now (instead of one), but shouldn't the property update no matter what?

Comment: Bindings try to be as lazy as possible. That means they don't recompute their values until they're actually needed. Since nothing needed the value of the `classTwoSize` property there was no reason to do the computations. A `ChangeListener` makes it eager because the listener needs both the old and new values in order to function properly.

Comment: Which I know is different than what you experienced [in your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65393285/conditional-binding-doesnt-work-as-expected), but I would consider that a bug (or at least unexpected behavior).

Comment: I believe the issue in this question is the same as the issue [in your more recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65482519/bindings-not-updating-properly), which comes from a mistake I made [in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65393285/conditional-binding-doesnt-work-as-expected). I've answered the more recent question and updated my answer to your previous question. With that in mind, I think this question can be a duplicate of either. You may want to consider deleting this one.