# Bindings not updating properly

Tags: java, javafx

Yet another binding issue from me. I already know that bindings are lazy, so they don't update when they don't need to, but this case is weird.

The code below gives me the following output:

```
minWidth calculation [150.0]
minHeight calculation [150.0]
minWidth calculation [0.0]
minWidth calculation [0.0]
minHeight calculation [0.0]
minHeight calculation [0.0]
```

It looks like `Bindings.select()` doesn't trigger binding calculation when when `ClassTwo` changes `width` or `height`. I think so, because when I execute `classTwo.getWidth()` at the end of the `start()` method, it returns the correct value (not 0). Any ideas?

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ClassOne classOne = new ClassOne();
        ClassTwo classTwo = new ClassTwo();

        ObjectProperty<ClassTwo> classTwoProperty = classOne.classTwoProperty();
        classTwoProperty.set(classTwo);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(classOne.getRootNode()));
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.minWidthProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
            ClassTwo value = classTwoProperty.get();
            double minWidth = value == null ? 75 : value.getWidth();
            System.out.println("minWidth calculation [" + minWidth + "]");
            return minWidth;
        }, classTwoProperty, Bindings.select(classTwoProperty, "width")));
        primaryStage.minHeightProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
            ClassTwo value = classTwoProperty.get();
            double minHeight = value == null ? 75 : value.getWidth();
            System.out.println("minHeight calculation [" + minHeight + "]");
            return minHeight;
        }, classTwoProperty, Bindings.select(classTwoProperty, "height")));

        ClassTwo classTwoSecondInstance = new ClassTwo();
        classTwoSecondInstance.setForcedWidth(100);
        classOne.setClassTwo(classTwoSecondInstance);
    }

}
```

**ClassOne.java**

```
public final class ClassOne {

    private final HBox rootNode = new HBox();

    public ClassOne() {
        classTwo.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (oldValue != null) {
                rootNode.getChildren().remove(oldValue.getRootNode());
            }
            if (newValue != null) {
                rootNode.getChildren().add(newValue.getRootNode());
            }
        });
    }

    public HBox getRootNode() {
        return rootNode;
    }

    //classTwo

    private final ObjectProperty<ClassTwo> classTwo = new SimpleObjectProperty<>
            (ClassOne.this, "classTwo", null);

    public ObjectProperty<ClassTwo> classTwoProperty() {
        return classTwo;
    }

    public void setClassTwo(ClassTwo value) {
        classTwo.set(value);
    }

    public ClassTwo getClassTwo() {
        return classTwo.get();
    }

}
```

**ClassTwo.java**

```
public final class ClassTwo {

    private final VBox rootNode = new VBox();

    public ClassTwo() {
        rootNode.minWidthProperty().bind(forcedWidth);
        rootNode.maxWidthProperty().bind(forcedWidth);
        width.bind(rootNode.widthProperty());
        height.bind(rootNode.heightProperty());
    }

    public VBox getRootNode() {
        return rootNode;
    }

    //width

    private final ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper width = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper
            (ClassTwo.this, "width", 50);

    public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty widthProperty() {
        return width.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public double getWidth() {
        return width.get();
    }

    //height

    private final ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper height = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper
            (ClassTwo.this, "height", 50);

    public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty heightProperty() {
        return height.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height.get();
    }

    //forcedWidth

    private final DoubleProperty forcedWidth = new SimpleDoubleProperty
            (ClassTwo.this, "forcedWidth", 150.0);

    public DoubleProperty forcedWidthProperty() {
        return forcedWidth;
    }

    public void setForcedWidth(double value) {
        forcedWidth.set(value);
    }

    public double getForcedWidth() {
        return forcedWidth.get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is my fault. When I gave a solution to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65393285/conditional-binding-doesnt-work-as-expected) I forgot to take into account that the objects returned by the `selectXXX` methods are bindings themselves. Bindings (and really all observables) are as lazy as possible in core JavaFX. When they're invalidated they simply notify any registered `InvalidationListener` and will remain invalid until their value is queried<sup>1</sup>. If a binding is invalid it can't become "more invalid" so (potentially) changing the value of an already-invalid binding does not notify any listeners.

And that's where the issue lies: The `createDoubleBinding` is dependent on a `select` binding that *is never queried*.

The following should solve the problem:

```java
DoubleBinding width = Bindings.selectDouble(classTwoProperty, "width");
primaryStage.minWidthProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
  ClassTwo value = classTwoProperty.get();
  if (value == null) {
    return 75.0;
  }
  // query the 'width' binding in order to validate it
  return width.get();
}, classTwoProperty, width));
```

I have also updated the solution in my answer to your other question.

---

<sup>1. *Querying an `Observable` makes it valid again. Note that if an `ObservableValue` has a `ChangeListener` registered then it stops being lazy (i.e. becomes eager). That's due to the fact that a `ChangeListener` requires both the old value and the new value in order to function properly.*</sup>