# JavaFx: How to bind to a not null or empty list?

Tags: javafx

This works:

```
getTableView().itemsProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldVal, newVal) -> button.setDisable(newVal == null || newVal.isEmpty()));
```

When the tableview items are null or empty, the button is disabled.

I was wondering if there is a "binding" solution and how it would be implemented.

```
button.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.or(Bindings.isNull(getTableView().itemsProperty()), Bindings.isEmpty(getTableView().getItems())));
```

The above does not work because `itemsProperty` is never `null` and `getItems()` may be null causing the `Bindings.isEmpty()` to fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ItemsProperty` of the `TableView` is a simple [ObservableProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/ObjectProperty.html) which does not provide any specialized functionality for tracking the items in an `ObservableList.`

You will want to create a [ListProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/ListProperty.html) instead, which in turn provides the `emptyProperty` that you can use for your purposes:

```
ListProperty<String> listProperty = new SimpleListProperty<>();;
```

Now bind that property to observe the `ItemsProperty` of the `TableView`:

```
listProperty.bind(tableView.itemsProperty());
```

The last step is just binding the `disableProperty` of your `Button`:

```
button.disableProperty().bind(listProperty.emptyProperty());
```

---

Below is a complete example using a `ListView` instead of a `TableView`. The functionality is identical but for the purposes of this example, a `ListView` is just quicker to implement.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ListProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleListProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ButtonBindingToList extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // **********************************************************************************************
        // Create a basic layout
        // **********************************************************************************************
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        // **********************************************************************************************
        // Creat the ListView
        // **********************************************************************************************
        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();

        // **********************************************************************************************
        // Create a Button to add items to the list (will always be enabled).
        // **********************************************************************************************
        Button btnAdd = new Button("Add item");
        btnAdd.setOnAction(event -> listView.getItems().add("Added item #" + listView.getItems().size()));

        // **********************************************************************************************
        // Create button to remove the last item in the ListView
        // **********************************************************************************************
        Button btnRemove = new Button("Remove last item");
        btnRemove.setOnAction(event -> listView.getItems().remove(listView.getItems().size() - 1));

        // **********************************************************************************************
        // In order to bind to the emptiness of the ListView, we need to create a ListProperty that
        // is bound to the ListView's itemsProperty
        // **********************************************************************************************
        ListProperty<String> listProperty = new SimpleListProperty<>();
        listProperty.bind(listView.itemsProperty());

        // **********************************************************************************************
        // Now bind the "Remove" button's disable property to the listProperty. This will disable
        // the button as long as the ListView is empty
        // **********************************************************************************************
        btnRemove.disableProperty().bind(listProperty.emptyProperty());

        root.getChildren().addAll(listView, btnAdd, btnRemove);

        // **********************************************************************************************
        // Set the Scene for the stage
        // **********************************************************************************************
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));

        // **********************************************************************************************
        // Configure the Stage
        // **********************************************************************************************
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test Application");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you can use `btnRemove.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(listView.itemsProperty()))`

Comment: @Alex No, you unfortunately can't (as the answer tries to explain). The `ListView` and `TableView` classes define their "items property" as an `ObjectProperty<ObservableList<T>>`. There is no `Bindings#isEmpty(...)` overload which accepts any parameterization of `ObjectProperty` as an argument. It would have been better and much more convenient if the API had used `ListProperty<T>` but I believe that class was developed later.

Comment: @Slaw Oh yeah. That was my mistake

Comment: @Slaw but `Bindings.isEmpty(listView.getItems())` should work

Comment: @Alex Yes, that would work provided `setItems(newList)` is never called. Otherwise a `ChangeListener` is still needed.

Comment: @Alex _but Bindings.isEmpty(listView.getItems()) should work_ not if items is null at the moment of binding (which seems to be the OP's context - which s/he prefers not to elaborate on), that's unusual but possible

Comment: @kleopatra yeah i didn't read whole question before my comments - that's my fault :(

Comment: btw: the underlying reason the NPE is thrown is a pecularity of how bindings (or more precisely ExpressionHelper) are implemented - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65393285/conditional-binding-doesnt-work-as-expected answered by @Slaw